# Expand section UITableview getting crash when reloadSections

Tags: iphone, ios

Trying to expand the sections each section will have two rows when expanded. It is giving crash. Below is code am trying.

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [self.mArrQues count];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(!helpOn)
    return 1;
else
    if(section == selectedCellIndexPath)
    {
    return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.mHelpTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

UIView* myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
//[cell addSubview:myBackgroundView];

if(!helpOn)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
else
{
if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
else{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.mArrAns objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
helpOn = !helpOn;

int ind = indexPath.section;
if(ind == selectedCellIndexPath)
{
}
else{
    helpOn = 1;
}
if(helpOn)
{
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section;
[self.mHelpTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    //selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section;
    [self.mHelpTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
}
```

Error :

`Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Answer (score 2):

As you are changing the number of cells at section, you need to wrap the reload operation with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` as well as specify the cells insertion and removal with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Alternatively you can use 'reloadData` to reload all the cells, however there will be problems  either with animation or user experience if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your code.

```
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

There is no need to alloc your cell if it is nil, tableview will reuse from previous cell in this line

```
cell = [self.mHelpTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

AND

Make in .h

```
int selectedCellIndexPath;
BOOL selected;
```

in .m

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    if (section==selectedCellIndexPath)
    {
        //selected > this is because initialy selectedCellIndexPath is 0 and section is also 0
        if (selected) {
        return 2;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [self.mHelpTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    UIView* myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
    //[cell addSubview:myBackgroundView];

    //if(!helpOn)
    if (indexPath.section!=selectedCellIndexPath)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
    else
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel.text = [mArrAns objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        }
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [self.mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selected= !selected;
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section;
    //selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.row;
    [self.mHelpTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

Comment: even i tested it but giving the same error, i am updating my code, i tried something different it starts expanding now but issue is if one section is expanded at same time other can not it crash.

Comment: Dont use this if(!helpOn)
    return 1;

Comment: i just replaced if(!helpOn) with
    if (indexPath.section==selectedCellIndexPath)

Comment: I want to send you code i implemented pls check that if you can?

Comment: rajneesh071@gmail.com

Comment: sent pls check in your mail.

Comment: what was it Rajneesh?

Comment: no not solved tried a lot but problem is coming in numberofrowsinsection method.

Comment: have u checked your mail?

Comment: ya haven't got yet anything from your side.

Comment: Did you send anything?

Comment: sorry buddy that was not send due to network problem, now check

Comment: I have checked the project you sent but the output is same. It is expanding one section only at a time if try to multiple sections expansion it crashes with same error. Anyway thanks for your efforts and giving time to my problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34680/discussion-between-iphone-6-and-rajneesh071)